# Loading from database without proxy classes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco, proxy-classes

In Entity Framework 4 Is it possible to choose to load some queries into a POCO without it using proxy classes? (For the purpose of caching that object for future read only use).  I am using the Repository - Service pattern.

By this I mean:

```
var order = _orderService.GetById(1);
// after order is loaded then we can see in the debugger that:
// order.Customer is of type System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxy.Customer_17631AJG_etc
```

What I want is for the `order.Customer` to actually use the POCO type `MyApp.Models.Entities.Customer` instead of a proxy to that type.

EDIT: Based on Ladislav's suggestion to add a "GetUnproxied" method to the Repository, I've made this change:

```
// this is the current method that must return a DynamicProxy
public IQueryable<T> GetQuery()
{
    return ObjectSet.AsQueryable();
}

// this is the new additional method that must return the plain POCO
public IQueryable<T> GetReadOnly()
{
    ObjectContext.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    var readOnly = ObjectSet.AsQueryable();
    ObjectContext.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
    return readOnly;
}
```

Is this correct?

It does not look thread safe to me.  Both methods use the same ObjectContext instance, so it might be possible for `ProxyCreationEnabled == false` to happen on one thread and then `public IQueryable<T> GetQuery()` to be called on another thread - which would suddenly mean that the proxy method could return the non proxied object.

Comment: I assume that you are using WCF Generated Proxies by adding "Service References" to your project. Is this correct?

Comment: @Yigit Ah no I'm using T4 templates to generate my POCO classes. Nothing to do with WCF.  What I'm saying is that when I use objectcontext.Get() that it loads the properties of the POCO as proxy classes instead of the actual POCO class

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use this before you query data to turn off proxy creation

```
context.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

I think it can be also turned off globally in EDMX designer.

### Update:

This applied to `ObjectContext`. With `DbContext` the code is:

```
context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

plus I do not see any option in the edmx designer

Comment: updated question to have two repository methods, one proxied, one without. Can you comment if it is correct, it does not look thread safe to me.

Comment: Yes it should work this way. I don't understand your comment about "thread safe". Nothing in EF is thread safe and context should not be shared among threads!

Comment: I've just tested it - debugged through line by line, and it calling the GetReadOnly() method, but it still returns a Dynamic Proxy, why would it do that?  The code that calls GetReadOnly is: `return _currencyRepository.GetReadOnly().Where(c => c.CurrencyCode == defaultCurrencyCode).FirstOrDefault();`.  It did execute the line `ProxyCreationEnabled = false` so I'm not sure why it is still a proxy.

Comment: I see, it is because deferred query execution. You cannot return `IQuerybale` - you must execute query before you set proxy creation back to true.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka  I thought `FirstOrDefault()` did execute query?