# A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type in asp.net and sql

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, extjs

I am trying to fill gridpanel to get data from database through LINQ in .net framework 3.5 MVC and in Extjs MVC.

I am able to archive to get all data sucessfully from following code

```
public Object Get()
{
     var employeeList = _db.Employees;
     var result = new
     {
         data = employeeList
     };
     return this.Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

but when i am passing data to extjs model it will give following Error
[image]

I am able to get my all data from database but Don't know where I am wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The circular reference is caused by the Json serialization.

See my post here: [Preventing StackOverflowException while serializing EF object graph into Json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9201020/290343)

This post might also help you: [EntityFramework to Json workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7611766/290343)

Comment: Ofer Zelig i had read your post and i am implementing [ScriptIgnore] but I am getting error like **Attribute 'ScriptIgnore' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'property, indexer, field' declarations.**

Comment: So do as the exception says... you probably didn't put [ScriptIgnore] on the right place, as it says.

Comment: What we do with Silverlight ? there is no system.web.extn.. Can i have a alternative ?

Comment: You can still reference System.Web etc.