# Redis .StoreAll An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, redis

I´m using Redis, but the `StoreAll` doesn´t work.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

```
var newOrders = (from i in DB.Produtoes.OrderByDescending(d => d.idProduto) select i);
using (var produtosRedis = redisClient.GetTypedClient<Produto>())
{
    produtosRedis.StoreAll(newOrders);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've encountered is a circular reference caused by the Json serialization used by `StoreAll()`.

These posts will help you:

1. [Preventing StackOverflowException while serializing EF object graph into Json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9201020/290343)
2. [EntityFramework to Json workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7611766/290343)